# node express-myconnection mysql pool : connection closed by server

Tags: node.js

I have a node server that create a connection pool to mysql, if there has been no activity for a period of time the connection is closed by server and and further access throws an error. Not sure where to go with this, have researched a number of forums with little luck.

```
var mysql       = require('mysql');
var connection = require('express-myconnection');

// DB connection
var dbOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'data',
    multipleStatements: true,
    connectionLimit: 20
};

app.use(connection(mysql, dbOptions, pool));
```

Error

```
Whoops there is an uncaught error Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/opt/www/CMI_intern_2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:109:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/www/CMI_intern_2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection pool works fine, there was a hidden database connection in some old code that was the root cause. Non issue.

Answer (score 0):

actually, if someone experiences those errors while calling localhost adding database option
    socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
solve this problem